# Java Stringbuilder implementing void method

Tags: java, stringbuilder, void

I am confused about StringBUilder.append(). Netbeans say that void type not allowed.

Here is the the  my  Java class named Levencthein.java

```
 public void printDistance(String s1, String s2) {
    System.out.println( computeEditDistance(s1, s2) + " ("+similarity(s1, s2) * 100 +")");
}
```

now, in the other class, assumpted in b.java

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
for (final JCCDFile file : files) {

        LevenshteinDistance lv = new LevenshteinDistance();
        if (idLexerSelection != getIDLexer()) {
            System.out.println(temp.getName() + " ==> " + file.getName());

            s.append(lv.printDistance(name1, name2)); This is the error


            sb.append(file.getName());
        }
    }
```

any solution ?

Answer (score 5):

You are attempting to append the return value of `printDistance`, but there is no return value because it's `void`.  In `printDistance`, instead of printing the value, return it.

```
return computeEditDistance(s1, s2) + " ("+similarity(s1, s2) * 100 +")";
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append the void return of `printDistance` to a `StringBuilder` (as the compiler is telling you). If I understand you, then this

```
public void printDistance(String s1, String s2) {
  System.out.println( computeEditDistance(s1, s2) 
      + " ("+similarity(s1, s2) * 100 +")");
}
```

Should return `String` and I'd return [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) like

```
public void printDistance(String s1, String s2) {
  return String.format("%s (%s)", computeEditDistance(s1, s2), 
      similarity(s1, s2) * 100);
}
```

Assuming that `computeEditDistance()` and `similarity()` return `String`. If they return `int` replace the `%s` in format with `%d` (or `%f` for floating point).